Sorting unbound DataGridView column, alphanumerically in Windows Forms app
I can't seem to find a current updated answer. The basic functionality works for me, where it will automatically sort a list like:
001.15
1
2
3
some
string

but my biggest issue is if I added a number, say '100', my list will now be:
001.15
1
100
2
3
some
string

I would like to see 100 after 3.
The single column I'm looking to sort by, 'Test ID', will contain strings, integers, and doubles.
I've tried many things, including a method called every time a button is pressed:
private void SortDVG(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Column.Index == 0)
     {
         e.SortResult = int.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()).CompareTo(int.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString()));
         e.Handled = true;
     }
 }

with a reference in a button click as
SortDVG(dataGridView1, (DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs)e);

but this throws a runtime errors because it registers as a mouse event, which makes sense to me.

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs'.'

and I've even tried just one line (this is what gave me the ordering in the first place)
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);

At a bit of a loss right now and looking to be pointed in the right direction

Could you clarify, because you say "my biggest issue is if I added a number, say '100', my list will now be..." but I don't see a specification like "but it should be...". Maybe just edit and state exactly what the desired outcome is.

@IV. Apologies, I made a small edit to the question.

If your goal is to perform a strict alphanumeric sort on a column that contains mixed types, you can safely achieve this by handling the SortCompare event and:

Get string values for e.CellValue1 and e.CellValue2, converting any null values to string.Empty.
Set the SortResult by comparing the strings.
IMPORTANT: Set e.Handled to true



public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        {
            Name = "TestId",
            AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells,
        });
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        {
            Name = "Description",
            AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill,
        });
        dataGridView.SortCompare += DataGridView_SortCompare;
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(001.15, "First item with decimal");
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(1, "Single digit integer");
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(100, "Triple digit integer");
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(2, "Another single digit integer");
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(3, "Yet another single digit integer");
        dataGridView.Rows.Add("some string", "String example");
    }

    private void DataGridView_SortCompare(object? sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
    {
        var a = e.CellValue1?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        var b = e.CellValue2?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        e.SortResult = a.CompareTo(b);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}


Alternative: Sort numbers with numbers
If on the other hand you want a kind of hybrid sort, where "numbers are compared to numbers" then you will get a slightly different result by attempting conversions to double.

private void DataGridView_SortCompare(object? sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    var a = e.CellValue1?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
    var b = e.CellValue2?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
    if (double.TryParse(a, out double value1) &&
        double.TryParse(b, out double value2))
    {
        e.SortResult = value1.CompareTo(value2);
    }
    else
    {
        e.SortResult = a.CompareTo(b);
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}

NOTE: By default, you can sort on a column by clicking the column header. You can also call DataGridView.Sort(...) to do the same thing programmatically.

Thank you @IV. for the answer. The alternative snippet you gave is what I was missing. Also, I was trying to pass something similar to this snippet as it's own method during a button click and it took me stepping away for a few days and coming back to understand why that isn't possible.

There is a small typo in this phrase: "Get string values for e.CellValue1 and e.CellValue1", it should be: "Get string values for e.CellValue1 and e.CellValue2".

@ShahramAlemzadeh thx! Good eye!

You have a very strange cast here:
SortDVG(dataGridView1, (DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs)e);

where e is the button event arguments object of type EventArgs. The Button class knows nothing about the DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs specialized event arguments class and does not pass instances to any of its events implicitly or explicitly. Therefore, you cannot make such a conversion.
However, you can convert the EventArgs of the Button.Click event to MouseEventArgs if - and only if - the button is clicked by the mouse. This happens because the base class, in the OnMouseUp method override, passes the same event argument object of type MouseEventArgs to the OnClick and OnMouseClick methods to raise the Click and MouseClick events as well.

As for the sorting problem, you need to compare the values logically where the digits in the strings are considered as numerical content rather than text. P/Invoking the StrCmpLogicalW function provides such a comparison.
▶ Example
Create a method that basically raises the DataGridView.SortCompare event by calling the DataGridView.Sort method and sets the direction of the sort-glyph. The method can be called from the button's Click event, grid's ColumnHeaderMouseClick event, and elsewhere. The SortCompare event P/Invokes the StrCmpLogicalW method and handles the logical comparison.
// In some Form { }
private void dgv_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    e.SortResult = StrCmpLogicalW(
            e.CellValue1?.ToString(),
            e.CellValue2?.ToString());

    e.Handled = true;
}

private void dgv_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(
    object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        SortDGV(dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]);
}

private void sortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SortDGV(dgv.Columns[0]);
}

private void SortDGV(DataGridViewColumn column)
{
    column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
    ListSortDirection dir = dgv.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending
        ? ListSortDirection.Descending
        : ListSortDirection.Ascending;

    dgv.Sort(column, dir);
    column.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = dgv.SortOrder;
}

[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);


Yes please excuse the weird cast, blame it on inexperience lol. I appreciate you explaining the reasoning, this was a learning experience for sure.

@MattTrembley No problem and you're welcome. However, in your code snippet, and as a mixed-type column, 001.15 formatted value should precede 1, 2, 3 and not be converted and compared as a numerical value. No? I can't see in the accepted answer 001.15! Also, if you have a string 99 some string, where it should be? before 100 or before some string.

@MattTrembley Also, DGV columns have ValueType property that returns one type only and used in sorting and filtering. It directs which IComparer implementation should be used in sorting routines. Mixed column values should be handled as of type object or string in this context. Since you're learning, think about these points and happy new year.
